# Laravel, перенаправление, если уже авторизован

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать перенаправление со страницы входа, если пользователь уже авторизовался? То есть после авторизации, я могу повторно зайти на страницу ввода логина/пароля, ввести туда любую белиберду и всё равно смогу войти, так как уже вошёл с правильными данными до этого.

Comment: ну как - делаете проверку что пользователь уже авторизирован, и делаете редирект

Comment: Прочитайте документацию. Там все детально написано. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Для Ваших маршрутов входа и регистрации поставьте `guest` Middleware.

Вариант №1:

```php
Route::middleware(['guest'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Вариант №2:

```php
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index'])->middleware('guest');
```

Затем в `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` настройте путь, на который будет перекидывать авторизованного пользователя:

```php
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```